# VLC PLAYLISTS. How do I delete individual tracks/songs from the Playlist

Tags: vlc-media-player

How do I delete individual tracks/songs from a VLC playlist?
If I right-click the unwanted track the "remove from list" option is there....If I click it the track disappears...... ***but re-appears when the Playlist is reopenned***.
This has cost me hours of frustration. How can something so basic be so hard?
Thanks

Comment: If you forgot to *save* the playli9st, just open the playlist, which has .xspf extension, and edit it in Notepad or an XML editor.

Answer (score 0):

VLC is not the most standards-compliant app known to humankind - but don't knock it because it's *good* & it's *free*, made by people donating their time & effort to this,so we can enjoy its benefits.

If you change a VLC playlist, you have to save the playlist again.
It's that simple.
It has no auto-save, no auto-reload next time you launch it, no remember where I was through relaunch/reboot…

Answer (score 0):

The updates you do to the list while playing are not recorded anywhere.

The only way is to save the playlist under a new name, which can even be
the same name in order to overwrite.
You do that by right-click on any entry in the list and select
"Save Playlist to File...".

You will need to then clear the existing playlist and open
the new one.

Comment: Thank you Sooooh much Tetsujin & harrymc.  It worked!!!!

Comment: Please consider choosing the answer which helped you the most and mark it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).